# Should I use native android junit framework?

Tags: unit-testing, android

Can anybody share a reason (or list of reasons) of not using the native android junit framework but a standalone one like robolectric or something like that?

I'm just trying to understand what framework to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main advantage of the bundled JUnit is that you don't have to bring additional dependencies into your project. JUnit is mature, well-documented and familiar-to-everybody framework. If you are not looking for sth special use JUnit.